# JPA 2, JSF, setting id of OneToOne mapped entity problem

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

we havent used JPA or any other ORM tools in our web application, now we have been on updating whole stuff to Java EE 6,
my problem about is JPA 
,i have been looking for an answer,and learn how people solve that kinda issue,
i have 2 entites,

```
@Entity Person
{
@Id
private long id;

@JoinColumn(name="CITY_ID")
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private City city;
....
}
```

and my second entity

```
@Entity City
{
@Id
private long id;
private String name;
.....
}
```

i am querying person entity and i show one on my jsf page

i have 2 input fields for Person.city to show on my jsf page
inputhidden for id and inputtext for name
people are selecting cities from a popup then 
i set hidden  component for city id, with new selected new value, 
and the same for name,
everthing goes fine till now,
when i merge Person Entity, it tries to merge City also, but with an id already defined on table, so constraint error for Cirty Id.

what are you doing for this kinda problem?

i thought valueChange action for inputHidden,but at jsf Life cycle it happens before update model so even if i replace Person.City entity with new one in action ,
it will updated again (actually with the same values but it will be done twice)
,So what is the best workaround for this situation?

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Seam Faces ,converter](http://bit.ly/gCssaS) as it explains in here u need special id to entity converter,
that was my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save a new Person and assign it to an existing City? If so, and if you are using PersistantManager.persist(person) than it tries to create a new City, which fails. You can tell the relationship from Person to City what options to follow, see [Cascading](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading) (MERGE in your case i guess).

Comment: no not new one, i am operating on managed entity,but ofcourse it mustnt delete city when i remove Person,let me check Cascade

Comment: it is not about cascade, there must be a conversion from id to entity in jsf life cycle

Comment: i have no idea about JSF. sorry